# php request inside a link

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink, request, magento-1.7

This is *.phtml template for a shipped by/tracking number table in a shipping email

```
 <?php $_shipment=$this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order=$this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order && $_shipment->getAllTracks()): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Shipped By') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Tracking Number') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
        <tr <?php echo $i%2?'bgcolor="#F6F6F6"':'' ?>>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $_item->getTitle() ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to change it so the tracking number becomes  a link to track the parcel, I found a link to track a parcel

```
http://www.parcelforce.com/portal/pw/track?trackNumber=[TRACKING NUMBER]
```

and tried to make it work like this

```
<a alt="Track package" href='http://www.parcelforce.com/portal/pw/track?trackNumber=<?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?>'><?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?></a>
```

it does not work. How do I make it right?

Comment: Could you post more code ? The way you've done it is the one it is supposed to be done usually, maybe the bug lies elsewhere.

Comment: If this is Magento-related as are your other questions, tag accordingly and show more code.

Comment: My main concern if do I need extra quotes like ?trackNumber="<?php ... ?>"

Comment: Maybe, try it out and see. Try all sorts of combinations. View your HTML source and see what comes of it. You need to "try" something.

Comment: Try something like `track?trackNumber="'<?php echo $_item->getNumber() ?>'"'>`

Comment: Post the exact HTML output you are receiving in the email.  That will show you exactly why it's not working.